# Golf mk4 climate control show speed instead of outside temperature

Tags: electrical, vw, diagnostics, climate-control

I know you can change climate control to show current speed when you enter diagnose mode but it gets reset after ignition restart and also you cant adjust your temperature or something like that while in that mode.

I'm wondering if you can to set it permanently to show speed instead of outside temperature using VCDS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik, the answer is **no**. Sorry.

The climate control diagnostics mode was meant to be used for quick checks if no diagnostic cable is available. There is no possibility to turn it on permanently.